# Products and Product Variants relationship. Adding variants through Filament

Tags: laravel, database, e-commerce, laravel-filament

I am tasked to create a dashboard for an e-commerce business, in general, using Laravel Filament. While designing the database I made sure to include the feature of adding variants. As a result, I came up with 4 tables:

- product_options (Color, Size)
- product_option_values (Blue,Large)
- product_variants
- product_option_value_variant (To support the many
  to many relationship between product_option_values and
  product_variants)

[image]

While creating the form I used the CheckBoxList (A filament component that returns an array of the option_value_id) to add the variants. And there I noticed that I am adding Color Blue Color Red and Size Large to one variant which made me realize that the relationship between options_values and variants is not a many to many relationship.

Here's a picture of the CheckBoxList that I used:

[image]

So, a variant can have many options but only one value to this option. What relationship is that?

---

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->hasMany(Relation::class)->distinct();
```

Comment: This should be the relationship in the ProductVariant Model? whats the inverse (in the ProductOptionValue Model)?

Comment: Also many relationship since many product can have many options and options belongs to many products

Comment: That's what I realised. Products have many options which is shared with other products. And each product has one value through an option.